# Alternative to hostname that does not depend on network connection

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I develop code designed to run with file systems on multiple computers. The data directory is synced across computers, but the particular location of the data directory on each computer is unique. To address this, I setup a paths file where the beginning of the path depends on which computer the code is running on. I determine which computer the code is running on using the `hostname` function.

This has started causing problems running code on my local machine, as the output depends on the particular network I connect to, which can be pretty random if I'm using wifi at a coffee shop.

Is there an alternative to `hostname` that will return something that identifies I am using my local machine and is not affected by my particular network connection?

Comment: Use file `/etc/machine-id` as unique machine id. `man 5 machine-id`. But I'm not sure, if Mac supports it too.

Comment: @Wiimm This is promising! Where is this file on mac? My local machine is a mac so this is all happening through terminal.

Comment: Since each computer has the data in a unique place can't you base the machine you are on off of the existence of these directories?

Comment: Mac has a unique serial number that can be accessed via `ioreg -l | grep IOPlatformSerialNumber`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of options for this. You could get the Mac's serial number or hardware UUID (see [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40243/how-can-i-find-the-serial-number-on-a-mac-programmatically-from-the-terminal)):

```
SerialNumber=$(ioreg -c IOPlatformExpertDevice -d 2 | awk -F\" '/IOPlatformSerialNumber/{print $(NF-1)}')
HardwareUUID=$(ioreg -c IOPlatformExpertDevice -d 2 | awk -F\" '/IOPlatformUUID/{print $(NF-1)}')
```

There's also the hardware address of the first network interface:

```
en0MAC=$(ifconfig en0 | awk '$1=="ether" {print $2}')
```

If you prefer to use the computer name as it's set in the Sharing pane of System Preferences (or the mDNS compatible version of it):

```
ComputerName=$(scutil --get ComputerName)
LocalHostName=$(scutil --get LocalHostName)
```

Warning: the computer name may contain spaces and other weird characters, so be extra-sure to double-quote any references to that variable to avoid parsing problems.